# GET requests to a POST handling view

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view intended to deal only with POST requests that starts with

```
user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['name'])
```

Do I need to ensure the view is not invoked with a GET request? Not sure if I'm thinking about good practice/security-type things or being OCD.

I'm using the `@require_POST` decorator because invoking the view with GET results in `"Key 'name' not found in <QueryDict: {}>` and a 500 error.

I suppose the only chance of this happening is if a user looked at the HTML of the page and for some reason thought to try the `action` attribute of the form in the address bar -which seems unlikely.

I've tried this myself with a couple of sites and got a error page, rather than a blank page with 405 error that `@require_POST` gives me.

Perhaps it's good practice to guard against GET requests in case a template designer mistakenly makes a hyperlink to my view or forgets `method="post"`? (In which case, I suppose I should use `get_object_or_404` above)

I assume adding `@require_GET` to views that are only designed to deal with GET requests is unnesessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to ensure the view is not invoked with a GET request? Not
>   sure if I'm thinking about good practice/security-type things or being
>   OCD.

Yes. I think you touch on answering your own question.  your view requires `request.POST` a get request errors. If you wnat to create bug free code you will ensure that no get requests access this view.  Django provides a convenient, pythonic, decorator to do this.  I don't think you are being OCD at all.  Also, I don't know how expensive it is to trigger an error in production (emails you, logs it, etc) but that is something to consider.

> I suppose the only chance of this happening is if a user looked at the HTML of the page and for some reason thought to try the action
>   attribute of the form in the address bar -which seems unlikely.

I dont think it matters HOW a user could make a GET request to this, i think it only matters that this view MUST be a post request.

> Perhaps it's good practice to guard against GET requests in case a
>   template designer mistakenly makes a hyperlink to my view or forgets
>   method="post"? (In which case, I suppose I should use
>   get_object_or_404 above)

In this case i dont' think thinking about the many ways a get request could be made to this view is important.  The important part is it REQUIRES a Post request.  You can use the tools at your disposal to ensure that all requests entering the function are post requests.

One thing is, `name` is not assumed.  You could still get a `KeyError`.  Even though you are ensuring that the request is POST you can't ensure that the post request will have a parameter `name`

that is why [`get`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) is used so frequently

```
if not request.POST.get('name'):
  # raise some sort of error?
user = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['name'])
```

Comment: Is EAFP style and a 500 error appropriate? try: username = request.POST['name'] except KeyError: return HttpResponseServerError('bad name')

Comment: I think it's completely appropriate, I think the main issue is you controlling an error, not letting unhandled conditions control the error. I believe your try statement is a great why to handle the problem

Comment: whoops I meant `return HttpResponseServerError('Error: user required')`

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you understand why you would want to use `@requirePOST`. Another option, if you did not want to cause an error on `GET`, is to use something along these lines:

```
def view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ..code for post..
    else:
        *redirect, or other code*
```

As to whether or not you need to use `@requireGET`, the only way it could hurt is if you need a view to perform both `GET` and `POST`. ie a form that causes action on `POST`, but is simply displayed for the user on `GET`. But if you are requiring `GET` then there should not be anything in the view that could be compromised via a `POST`.